# Pass an array to a PowerShell script as separate arguments

Tags: arrays, powershell, arguments

I thought this would be simple to do, but I am stuck.

Script1.ps1 contains:

```
$params = "abc", "def"
Script2 $params
```

Script2.ps1 contains:

```
Args.Count
```

This of course will output "1" for the single array argument that Script2 receives.

I want to find a way to pass $params not as a single array, but as two separate arguments  -- so that Script2 outputs "2" for the count and args[0] is "abc" and args[1] is "def".

I tried all different ways to do this, but I never ended up with what I wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
$params = "abc", "def"
Script2 @params
```

Comment: This technique is called "splatting."

Comment: Thanks. One thing that was confusing me was something that I just noticed about $args.  If include the expression, $args.Count, in the script, it prints the correct value. But if I put a breakpoint on this expression and type $args.Count in the command window, it always displays "0".